# ultimate encryption and protection of sensitive data

Tags: anonymity, security, windows, browsers, encryption

I have many sensitive documentation which I am scared to lose or get somebody accessed. My question would be what is the ultimate encryption protection?  I have read lot of articles saying that for instance bitlocker is prone to cracking or reverse brute force password hacking. I am a little paranoic using 24 alfanumeric character password but still scared if reading articles as bellow saying there is tool to crack bitclocker protection.

[how to crack bitlocker](https://blog.elcomsoft.com/2016/06/breaking-bitlocker-encryption-brute-forcing-the-backdoor-part-i/)

Can any cipher professional say what tool is secure by ultimate way? I used veracryp, LUKS partition on Linux with AES256 but I am scared brute force attack especially with highly powerfull CUDA graphical card able to speedup brute force process significantly. Any professional advice would be highly welcomed. Kindest regards, Andy

Answer (score 1):

There is unfortunately no "ultimate encryption tool". However there are some tools, that if used correctly provide reasonable security.

These tools listed here are well known to provide strong enough encryption to resist currently known attacks, if used correctly.

**Tools:**

- [Veracrypt](https://veracrypt.fr)
- LUKS disk encryption
- [GPG](https://gnupg.org)

Not all tools listed here are usable for everything (e.g. you can't encrypt a partition with GPG).

Depending on what kind of sensitive documents you need to store, you might want to take a look at [Qubes OS](https://www.qubes-os.org).

Answer (score 1):

Don´t exists a "ultimate encryption tool" but with right tools e a little discipline is possible protect your files with a good encryption cipher and software, my recommendation is [Veracrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Downloads.html) with AES-Twofish-Serpent cascade cipher and SHA-512 Hash cipher, if your have some problem with SHA-512 you can use Whirlpool cipher instead, a community developed cipher with 512 bits like SHA-512.

[image: AES-Twofish-Serpent SHA-512 Encryption conf on veracrypt]

On Windows systems veracrypt also used for encryption hard disk offering a more trusted protection than Bitlocker using a AES-256 cipher.

On Linux/BSD systems LUKS disk encryption and GELi is best default options available instead Veracrypt or others softwares.

You can also use PGP with a key-pair RSA-4096 for encrypt text / email and even files.

Check this: Obs *Onion Hidden Services required Tor Browser.

[PGP Tutorial For Newbs (Gpg4Win)](http://deepdot35wvmeyd5.onion/2013/11/11/pgp-tutorial-for-newbs-gpg4win/)

[PGP Tutorial For Windows (Kleopatra – Gpg4Win)](http://deepdot35wvmeyd5.onion/2015/02/21/pgp-tutorial-for-windows-kleopatra-gpg4win/)

[Basic Guide to PGP On Linux](http://deepdot35wvmeyd5.onion/2015/02/17/basic-guide-pgp-linux/)

Finally... Your protection depends largely on your enemy and the amount of resources that they have, for common people combination of this softwares and good practices that's enough.

Answer (score 0):

I do know LUKS on Linux partition and frequently using but I have also windows desktop. I also know Veracrypt but I have red article saying that also Veracrypt is prone to cracking or brute force attacks.https://blog.elcomsoft.com/2016/07/breaking-bitlocker-encryption-brute-forcing-the-backdoor-part-ii/
Also bitlocker is not 100% safe.

No good reference about those tools saying how secure it shall be?